# Ember Data - destroy model from controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a Lead model defined with DS.Model and I noticed something weird when I was working with creating my app. When the REST resource doesn't return a resource in subsequent calls, the old data stays around. I tried to solve this by doing:

```
var model = this.get('model');
model.forEach(function(model) {
  model.destroy();
});
```

However, nothing happens. I have searched around but can't find the proper way to clear out a specific model cache and then refresh it with find(). I am using ember data 0.13

Comment: Clearing a model is tricky because of relationships, and isn't support at the moment. There is an discussion about it [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/235)

Comment: I was afraid this would still be the case but figured there was a high probability. I was hoping that maybe something updated but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
model.deleteRecord();
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it actually is requesting an HTTP delete. I ended up switching to backbone and ditching ember because of all of the problems. Much less hassle with bb. Sorry I can't accept this answer because it technically would be really bad if someone did this to clear a model.